# Pintándoles or pintándolos?

Tags: pronombres, laísmo-leísmo-loísmo

Which is better?  *Pintándoles* or *pintándolos*?

I've always had a lot of trouble choosing the right pronoun between *lo* and *le".  I have a feeling it's because I learned Spanish in Mexico.  I suspect there's more *lo* there, and more *le* in places like Spain and Colombia.

My audience will be Dominican readers of a scholarly journal.

The context is more or less like this:

> La imagen refuerza ciertos estereotipos comunes en Estados Unidos de negros, pintándoles de ignorantes etc.

Comment: they'll understand either one, if you are looking for a negative connotation tiñendoles/los would work better maybe. i dont think there is an equivalent in english (for the expression not the word, the word is dyeing)

Comment: @Rostol - That's a fancy word!  I'll offer it as an option in a comment.

Comment: It turns out we have a canonical question that addresses this: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/9385

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go with *pintándolos*. The form with *-les* is definitely something that you might hear in Spain but generally not elsewhere; its use is called *[leísmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo)*. The *le/les* forms, in standard Spanish, are reserved for the indirect object (or dative), while in the example you have *pintar*, which takes a direct object:

> *pintando **a los negros*** = *pintándo**los***

Note the difference if you wanted to say that someone is actually painting (on) black people's faces:

> *pintando las caras **a los negros*** = *pintándo**les** las caras*

The difference is that, despite the fact that they look the same, *a los negros* in the former example is the direct object (preceded by "[personal *a*](http://studyspanish.com/grammar/lessons/persa)" as usual) while in the latter it is the indirect object (preceded by the preposition *a* that marks IOs as a rule).

Wikipedia in Spanish [says](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo) that *leísmo* is found in several places in the Americas, often alternating with *la/lo*. At least in Argentina I'd say *leísmo* is extremely rare, possibly limited to a few verbs; in the case of your example it would be immediately be heard as wrong.

Comment: And now I have to decide between "dentro de un marco que le incluye" vs. "dentro de un marco que la incluye."  The pronoun refers to a person (woman).

Comment: @aparente001 By the same logic, it's *la incluye*. (I think there's no way to use *incluir* with an indirect object, unless it's a so-called "dative of benefit" - something like *le puedo incluir un extra en la oferta*.)

Comment: @pablodf76 _le puedo incuir_ also works if you are talking to an _Usted_

Answer (score 0):

I'm always pleased to help foreign people to understand our beautiful language.

Look, it's very easy, let's use as example the word *"instalar"* that translated to english is *"install"*

EXAMPLE: *"I'm going to install this in here"* --- *"Voy a instalar esto aquí"*

If I say: "Voy a instalarle esto" it means: *"I'm going to install this TO YOU "*  but it can also means: *"I'm going to install this TO HER"* or *"I'm going to install this TO HIM"*

In the other hand, if I say: "Voy a instalarlo" it means: *"I'm going to install it"*

Look that if I use *"lo"* in english is like putting the pronoun *"it"* at the end.
But when I use *"le"* I'm refering to another person, it can be *YOU*, it can be *HER* or it can be *HIM*.

Wait a minute! beacuse unfortunately is not that easy because there are some sentences that "le" or "lo" are ok in any context, for example in your sentence *"La imagen refuerza ciertos estereotipos comunes en Estados Unidos de negros, pintándoles de ignorantes etc."* is ok to use *"le"* or *"lo".*

It depends on the sentence. You will only understand what I'm saying living too much time in a spanish speaking country. But for ease of terms you can use the rule I explained above. I hope you have understood me. Thanks!

Comment: "Voy a instalarle esto" could also mean "I'm going to install this TO/FOR/ON you/him/her"

Comment: Suppose a political boss is going to install a protegé in a particular bureaucratic structure.  Le or lo?

Comment: Nor "le" nor "lo" none of those. The traduction would be "El jefe va a instalar un Protegé burocratico en su gobierno".