# 'Le' vs. 'lo': how big of a deal is it to confuse the two?

Tags: pronombres, laísmo-leísmo-loísmo

How egregious of an error is it to use 'lo' instead of 'le' or vice-versa (for example, saying 'yo le veo' instead of 'yo lo veo')?

In other words, is this more notable of an error than using the wrong gender for a noun? Sometimes I notice that native Spanish speakers confuse the two, but I'm not sure how 'wrong' it sounds to other native speakers.

I would also like to know how silly I sound to others when I make little errors like this. Thanks!

Comment: Great question. // Related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20104/pint%c3%a1ndoles-or-pint%c3%a1ndolos

Comment: "How silly" is a matter of opinion and therefore outside the scope of this forum, but really, I don't think anyone (who is an adult) will think you sound silly if you make little mistakes like these.

Answer (score 4):

> is this more notable of an error than using the wrong gender for a noun?

No. If you use the wrong gender for a word native Spanish speakers are going to notice immediately. On the other hand, as you know, with *leísmo* and *laísmo* people may be using the wrong form without noticing. Using the wrong gender is a more blatant error. *Leísmo* and *laísmo* are something you can definitely get away with or that may even go unnoticed.

The [Spanish version of wikipedia for leísmo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo) has much more info than its [English sibling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo). If you read it you can see how it is described as a "dialectal variation" and it is quite pervasive in certain areas (that you may find listed on the Spanish version of the wikipedia entry. See "[dialectos leístas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo#Dialectos_le.C3.ADstas)").

It is definitely not a big deal. See how there are even regions that favor these forms.

Comment: **On “Animacy” Marking:** Considering that Spanish also has special marking of an "animate" direct object via its “a personal”, it’s no surprise that at least some speakers distinguish an **animate** masculine direct object via “le” from an **inanimate** one via “lo”. This may be reinforced by its tripartite “gender” distinction in tonic/non-clitic pronouns: *ello/él/ella* and *esto/éste/ésta, eso/ése/ésa, aquello/aquel/aquella*. However Spanish doesn’t resemble the Latin “gender” model as much as it (somewhat) does the Asturian one, with their famous *“neutru de materia”*.